# Conditional Cell Formatting with NG-GRID

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a pretty basic grid with Angular.js using the NG-Grid plugin.
http://plnkr.co/edit/FRCndA

How can I prevent user from changing third Column to VALID if second column is blank,(Third Row).

Comment: Take a look at the comments of this questions (ng-if) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268522/make-only-some-cells-editable-in-nggrid