# Make only some cells editable in ngGrid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ngGrid that shows a few records with basically `key` / `value` content. Now, I would like to make *some* of these records editable.

Using the `enableCellEditing` features of ngGrid, I can enable or disable editin for a complete column - but what if I only want to enable it for some rows in that column? Is there any way to dynamically configure this for each row?

Comment: custom edit templates I think is the only way at the moment

Comment: But they are equal for all rows, aren't they? What, e.g., if I wanted to have a different kind of edit template depending on the cell content, e.g. different `input` fields for different data types?

Comment: Yes, but in the custom template you could look at a certain scope property or call a scope function to see if the cell should be editable.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see ... basically using `ng-if` or something like that inside the template, and calling a function on the scope with the cell as parameter to verify whether this cell should be editable, right?

Comment: Yeah, something like that would work.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but **ng-grid** (which is now being redone as **ui-grid**) now has a [`cellEditableCondition`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options) that you can use to make only some cells editable.

You just add it in your `gridOptions` :

```
enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
cellEditableCondition: 'row.rowIndex !== 2' //can edit all rows except for the third
```

[**Example plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7CGqwvVezI2PCv7l8iYS?p=preview)

This feature availble only after ng-grid 2.0.9

Answer (score 0):

You can use cellEditableCondition like below code

{ field: 'planTypeName',displayName:$rootScope.commonProperty.name,enableCellEditOnFocus: true,enableCellEdit:true,cellEditableCondition: function( $scope ) { return $scope.row.entity.sts=='A'; }},