# nggrid cell edit : get values before edit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268522/make-only-some-cells-editable-in-nggrid)

there is good example for editing cell in ngGrid. My question is : for cells with enabled editting what is the correct way to  get/store  value before editing   (for example to revert edited value ) . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can drop ngFocus in the editable cells and use it to cache its contents as soon the user clicks into one of the editable cells.